# Read from standard input with all MPI processes

Tags: io, fortran, mpi, stdin

So far I've been using `OPEN(fid, FILE='IN', ...)` and it seems that all MPI processes read the same file `IN` without interfering with each other.

Furthermore, in order to allow the input file being chosen among several, I simply made the `IN` file a symbolic link pointing to the desired input. This means that when I want to change the input file I have to run `ln -sf desidered-input IN` before running the program (`mpirun -n $np ./program`).

I'd really like to be able to run the progam as `mpirun -n $np ./program < input-file`. To do so I removed the `OPEN` statement, and the corresponding `CLOSE` statement, and changed all `READ(fid,*)` statements to `READ(INPUT_UNIT,*)` (I'm using `ISO_FORTRAN_ENV` module).

But, after all edits, I've realized that only one process (always `0`, I noticed) reads from it, since all others reach `EOF` immediately. Here is a MWE, using OpenMPI 2.0.1.

```
! cat main.f90
program main
    use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env
    use mpi
    implicit none
    integer :: myid, x, ierr, stat
    x = 12
    call mpi_init(ierr)
    call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world, myid, ierr)
    read(input_unit,*, iostat=stat) x
    if (is_iostat_end(stat)) write(output_unit,*) myid, "I'm out"
    if (.not. is_iostat_end(stat)) write(output_unit,*) myid, "I'm in", myid, x
    call mpi_finalize(ierr)
end program main
```

that can be compiled with `mpifort -o main main.f90`, run with `mpirun -np 4 ./main`, and which results in this output

```
               1 I'm out
               2 I'm out
               3 I'm out
    17 this is my input from keyboard
               0 I'm in           0          17
```

I know that MPI has proper routines to perform parallel I/O, but I've found nothing about reading from standard input.

Comment: Which MPI implementation do you use?  It is quite common for a single process only to get the standard input of `mpirun` (and sometimes controllable).

Comment: Open MPI v2.0.1

Comment: using `mpirun` with a redirection is discouraged, and should only be used when there is no other alternative (for example if the input file is only available on the node invoking `mpirun`). The reason is it involves out of band traffic which is suboptimal. This use case is also lightly tested and some bugs have been reported. Also, note `Open MPI 2.0.x` series is no more supported, and you should upgrade to `3.0.x` or at least `2.1.x` series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are seeing the [expected behaviour with OpenMPI](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v2.0/man1/mpirun.1.php#sect14).  By default, `mpirun`

> directs UNIX standard input to /dev/null on all processes except the MPI_COMM_WORLD rank 0 process. The MPI_COMM_WORLD rank 0 process inherits standard input from mpirun.

The option `--stdin` can be used to direct standard input to another process, but not to direct to all.

---

One could also note that the behaviour of redirection of standard input isn't consistent across MPI implementations (the notion isn't specified by the MPI standard).  For example, using Intel MPI there is the `-s` option to that `mpirun`.  `mpirun -np 4 -s all ./main` does allow all processes access to `mpirun`'s standard input.  There's also no guarantee that processes without that redirection will fail, rather than wait, to read.

Comment: Once one concludes this is the expected behaviour, the way to work with it could be clear.   Please comment if you'd like me to expand, though.

Comment: Satisfying answer and disappointing limitation of OpenMPI, since I think it goes in an opposite direction with respect to Unix philosophy. Well, it wouldn't be bad if you could expand your answer: How would you distribute process 0's standard input to all other processes? Is there something better than `MPI_BCAST`ing every single variable that `0` determined based on or read from stdin? In this moment I'm trying to broadcast to everyone the lines as they are read by `0`, so that every process can parse them independently.

Comment: Broadcasting input lines would be my first recommendation.  Admittedly that could get boring quite quickly.  Another option: populate then broadcast a "parameters" type.

Comment: do you mean defining a derived type to collect all stuff that is supposted to be set based on the input file?

Comment: Yes.  Such a derived type will also be useful for populating metadata in your result dataset and possibly for checkpointing/resumption.